# ndim Error with Statsmodels Tweedie Model

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a tweedie model with Statsmodel and keep getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Tweedie' object has no attribute 'ndim'

```
formula = 'pure_premium ~ atfault_model + channel_model_DIR + channel_model_IA + CLded_model + credit_model_52778 + \
        credit_model_c6 + package_model_Elite + package_model_LBO + package_model_Plus + package_model_Savers + \
        package_model_Savers_Plus + Q("ds_fp_paid_in_full_eligiable-has discount") + ds_fp_paid_in_full_ineligable + \
        Q("ds_pn_prior_insurance_eligable-has discount") + ds_pn_prior_insurance_ineligable + \
        Q("ds_ip_advanced_purchase_eligiable-has discount") + ds_ip_advanced_purchase_ineligable + \
        credit_model_c5 + ds_ad_affinity + ds_ak_alliance + \
        ds_ly_loyalty_discount + ds_mo_multipolicy + ds_pf_performance + majorvio_model + \
        (driver_age_model*marital_status_model) + minorvio_model + multi_unit_model + \
        RATING_CLASS_CODE_MODEL + unit_drv_exp_model +  Vintiles + safety_course_model + instructor_course_model + \
        (class_model*v_age_model) + (class_model*cc_model) + state_model'

lost_cost_model = smf.ols(formula = formula, data = coll_df
                          , family = sm.families.Tweedie(link = sm.families.links.log, var_power = 1.5))
```

Every variable is either a categorical, float or int.

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: There is not enough information to guess what might go wrong. Try to make a simplified example. Show at least the last part of the traceback where it shows where the exception occurs.

Comment: The mistake is obvious. `ols` does not take a family, OLS is just linear regression. You need to use the generalized linear model, i.e. `GLM` or `glm` for the formula interface.

Comment: Thanks @Josef. Want to put that into a post?  I’ll check it as an answer. If not, thanks anyways. Trying to move this from R to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ols` does not take a family, `OLS` is just linear regression.

You need to use the generalized linear model, i.e. `GLM` or `glm` for the formula interface.
`GLM` includes several families in the one parameter exponential family and includes a selection of link functions.

Several other models are equivalent to GLM but based on a different implementation and with other options. Those models are written for the specific family-link combinations and do not have an option to change those.

`OLS` is GLM with Gaussian family and linear link
`Logit` is GLM with Binomial family, logit link and only for binary response variables.
`Proit` is GLM with Binomial family, probit link and only for binary response variables.
`Poisson` is GLM with a Poisson family and log link
`NegativeBinomial` is a more general version of GLM with NegativeBinomial family and log link. `discrete.NegativeBinomial` allow for several parameterizations of the implied variance function and estimates the dispersion parameter jointly with the mean parameters as MLE.